# Issue with Canvas view in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, canvas

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></toolkit:GestureListener>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Black">
            <Canvas Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent">
                <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebView"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                              NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                              Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                              Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"
                              Canvas.Top="0"
                              Canvas.Left="0">
                </phone:WebBrowser>
                <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/StartScreen3.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                <GoogleAds:AdView Name="BannerAd"
                              AdUnitID="a14e0073dbc5ecb"
                              Format="Banner"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              ReceivedAd="AdView_ReceivedAd"
                              FailedToReceiveAd="AdView_FailedToReceiveAd">
                </GoogleAds:AdView>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

This is my MainPage.xaml file code where I have put my WebBrowser component inside a Canvas. Now my problem is, when I test this code on `Emulator WVGA 512MB` it looks fine like this
[image: Emulator Image 480x800]

But when I test it on `Emulator WXGA`(768x1280) WebBrowser is going out of the screen and looks like this
[image: Emulator Image 768x1280]

How can I fix it. Please help. I dont want to remove canvas view.

**EDIT**:
Got fixed with this. Thanks to @Vyas_27 and @KooKiz

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></toolkit:GestureListener>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Black">
            <Canvas Name="ContentPanelCanavas"
                    Background="Transparent">
                <GoogleAds:AdView Name="BannerAd"
                              AdUnitID="a14e0073dbc5ecb"
                              Format="Banner"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              ReceivedAd="AdView_ReceivedAd"
                              FailedToReceiveAd="AdView_FailedToReceiveAd">
                </GoogleAds:AdView>
            </Canvas>
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebView"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                              NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                              Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                              Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"
                              Canvas.Top="0"
                              Canvas.Left="0"
                              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
            </phone:WebBrowser>
            <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/StartScreen3.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your canvas, but put your WebBrowser control outside of it:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></toolkit:GestureListener>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Black">
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebView"
                          IsScriptEnabled="True"
                          IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                          ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                          NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                          Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                          Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted">
        </phone:WebBrowser>

        <Canvas Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent">                
            <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/StartScreen3.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
            <GoogleAds:AdView Name="BannerAd"
                          AdUnitID="a14e0073dbc5ecb"
                          Format="Banner"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          ReceivedAd="AdView_ReceivedAd"
                          FailedToReceiveAd="AdView_FailedToReceiveAd">
            </GoogleAds:AdView>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This way, it'll be correctly sized by the Grid, and you can still place the other controls as you wish by using the canvas.

Comment: This also didn't work. However I tried combination of your suggestion and @Vyas_27 answer. And it worked. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @PratPor You should edit your question to add your fixed code, in case someone else has the same issue

Comment: Ok I will update it. But now I have another issue. With the code you suggested, WebBrowser was becoming unresponsive, maybe because of AdView component placed after that. So I Changed their positions and defined Canvas after the WebBrowser in the sequence. But now ads are not showing up. What is wrong. How sequence of defining the elements withing same Grid affecting others. And how can I fix it

Answer (score 1):

try this see if it works;

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></toolkit:GestureListener>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Black">
            <Canvas Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent">
                <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebView"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                              IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                              NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                              Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                              Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"
                              Canvas.Top="0"
                              Canvas.Left="0">
                </phone:WebBrowser>
                <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/StartScreen3.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                <GoogleAds:AdView Name="BannerAd"
                              AdUnitID="a14e0073dbc5ecb"
                              Format="Banner"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              ReceivedAd="AdView_ReceivedAd"
                              FailedToReceiveAd="AdView_FailedToReceiveAd">
                </GoogleAds:AdView>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Just add;

```
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
```

to your webbrowser control.

Comment: try setting the canvas height and width with the above xaml & check if it works.

Comment: Thanks. This also didn't help. But adding height/width and @KooKiz answer worked. Thanks a lot for you help